# Move ImageView relatively to another imageView's position- Android Studio

Tags: android, sdk, imageview

I'm trying to make an ImageView follow another ImageView, by changing it's coordinates. My movement method is that:

public void move(double zx, double zy) {

```
    if (zx < a.getLeft()) {

        if (a.getLeft() - zx > 0) {

            a.setLeft(a.getLeft() - 1);

        } else

            a.setLeft(a.getLeft()+1);

    }
    if (zx > a.getLeft()) {

        if (a.getLeft() - zx > 0) {

            a.setLeft(a.getLeft() - 1);

        } else

            a.setLeft(a.getLeft() - 1);

    }

    if (zy > a.getTop()) {

        if (a.getTop() - zy > 0) {

            a.setTop(a.getTop() - 1);

        } else

            a.setTop(a.getTop() + 1);;

    }

    if (zy < a.getTop()) {

        if (a.getTop() - zy > 0) {

            a.setTop(a.getTop() - 1);

        } else

            a.setTop(a.getTop() + 1);

    }

}
```

OnCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fase);
    a = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.a);
    b = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.b);

    move(b.getLeft(), b.getTop());
}
```

"a" and "b" are the ImageViews, and a should follow b. I declared both ImageViews correctly, and the method should work. Instead of it, the ImageView "a" keep in the same position since the application starts. What is wrong? Is the method move declared at the wrong place (onCreate) ? I also have tried to just set the vertical position of "a" in another part of the screen, for testing if it would work. But it didn't (and according to the logCat it's vertical position had changed). The tutorials I found about moving images are based on dragging them, but I haven't still found anything about another kind of movement, like this.

There is my layout (activity_fase.xml) :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="thegame.app.Fase"
android:background="@drawable/seapaint">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/b"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/a"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="79dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/b"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/a"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/key"
    android:layout_marginBottom="67dp"
    android:src="@drawable/key"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/points"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

I'm new on android developing, and I don't know the difference between relative layout and linear layout.

Comment: Are you sure both `ImageView`s are in the same `RelativeLayout`, and not `LinearLayout`? Can you give me your layout view (activity_fase.xml)?

Comment: I added the layout view to the question.

Comment: At "a" `ImageView` (in your xml) you are using a property that would break any positioning rule. It's `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. That property forces a view to ignore any positioning, and place it on its parent view's bottom. So you have to remove it.

Comment: I did it, but the problem wasn't solved. I've read that the ImageIcon "a" should be in the LinearLayout, then I would be able to change it's gravity by code, defining a LinearLayout and setting it's parameters to "a". I also tried it, setting the gravity to 3, but the image just kept stopped at the left  of the screen, not expressing any movement from a region to another. Is there any other way to try it? Can it be done by setting new parameters to "a"?

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED

It's possible to change an ImageView's position for any region of the screen by setting a relativeLayout by code, and adding to it's parameters  the leftMargin and the topMargin. Example:

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80,80);
// 80 is just a number of my choice. There are many possibilities

params.leftMargin = 200;

params.topMargin = 400;

a.setLayoutParams(params);

Now the imageView's coordinates are (200,400). A successive change can be done. If you creat a timer that is called each 0.05 seconds and a task that adds 1 to the leftMargin and topMargin, the image's position will be successfully changed.